# Surjective map from a countable set to [0, 1]

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the map $\varphi$ from $A = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid 0 \leq x \leq 9  \}$ to $[0, 1]$ such that
$$
\varphi : (a_{1} , a_{2}, \dots) \mapsto 0.a_{1}a_{2}\dots
$$
Since $A$ is countable, and $\varphi$ is surjective (every real number in $[0, 1]$ has a decimal representation), $[0, 1]$ is also countable, which is not the case, what's wrong with the reasoning?

**Edit**: **$A$ is uncountable**. I thought that countable union of countable sets is countable, however in this case it's the countable **product** of countable set rather than **union**, it's the assumption that's wrong, not the conclusion.

Comment: Why is $A$ countable ?

Comment: You proved that $A$ is uncountable.

Comment: A countable product is not a countable union.

Comment: One could say that the cardinality of $A$ is $10^{\aleph_0}$ which is uncountable (and equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$).

Comment: Your final remark is incorrect. That is not a countable union. A countable union of countable sets is countable. But here we have countable **product** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since $A$ is countable

Unfortunately it is not. And this reasoning here can serve as a proof of that, assuming you already know that $[0,1]$ is uncountable.

If you don't, then the standard Cantor's diagonal argument applies. Assume that there is a sequence $f_{n}$ that covers whole $A$. So it is a sequence of sequences and thus $f_{n,m}$ makes sense.

Define $$a_k=(f_{k,k}+1)\text{ mod }10$$ There is nothing special about this formula. The point is that $a_k\neq f_{k,k}$. I've added mod only to stay in digits set. Any such choice will work. I leave as a simple exercise that $(a_k)$ cannot be in the image of $f_n$.